# Add new results to existing redux state "state not iterable" error

Tags: javascript, redux

This is showing a "state.users is not iterable" error. I want to append additional search results to the current list of users in state. I'm trying to do this by copying previous state and combining it with new state.

```
const initialState = {
 users: [],
 loading: false,
};


export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SEARCH_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [...state.users, action.payload.users],
        loading: false,
        };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sounds like you want the `users` to be an array, make sure the shape of the initial state matches the type returned in the reducer, so that it can be spread ad desired:

```
const initialState = {
  users: [],
  loading: false,
};
```

Objects can't be spread into arrays - only arrays and other iterables can be spread into arrays.

Comment: Double check that you've saved / re-compiled / re-run the code - given the code in the answer, it wouldn't make any sense for the error you describe to continue to occur.

Comment: How would the return statement change if I want users to be objects?

Comment: Do you mean that each individual *user* is an object? It wouldn't change at all.

Comment: If `action.payload.users` is an array of users, you'd want to spread it: `...action.payload.users` in the reducer, but that's a separate issue that shouldn't have anything to do with the error in your question